# Form using GET instead of POST, can't figure out why

Tags: php, html, forms

I've made lots of forms before and this one should be no different, but I just can't figure out what is wrong with it. It's a basic form that I want to use POST, but for some reason it is using get, and I can see all the info in the url on the action page. What is making it use GET instead of POST? This is all inside some php.

```
echo "
<div class='makeComment'>
<form action='commentHandler.php method='post'>
    Make a comment:<br>
    <textarea name='userComment' cols='78%' rows='5' maxlength='5000'></textarea><br>
    <input type='submit' class='commentSubmitButton'>
</form>
</div>
";
```

Comment: `'commentHandler.php` you forgot a closing quote so your method is being ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @chiliNUT, you forgot a quote (`'commentHandler.php`)

Your code:

```
echo "
<div class='makeComment'>
<form action='commentHandler.php' method='post'>
    Make a comment:<br>
    <textarea name='userComment' cols='78%' rows='5' maxlength='5000'></textarea><br>
    <input type='submit' class='commentSubmitButton'>
</form>
</div>
";
```

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten closing a quote on the form action, so php ignores your instructions and uses default GET